# Save Azure Active Directory user id

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, azure-active-directory

I'm looking for the best practice way of saving user identification data in my MVC application. Users authenticate onto the site using Azure AD. When a user saves data I want the "user id" to be saved on that record to uniquely identify it and also allow users to return their own set of data.

What is the best method to get the users AD unique identifier?

Answer (score 0):

Azure AD provides claim based authentication. You can retrieve authenticated user identifier from current `ClaimsPrincipal` object.

Comment: Thanks, this looks like what I need but what "user id" value do you recommend I put in the database? All I can see that looks like a unique identifier is the Name. I would of thought there is a GUID or something similar to store.

Comment: @user1476207, you can use `System.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier`.

Answer (score 0):

We use the `objectidentifier` or `oid` as mentioned on the page I've linked below.
The sub claim might also be the right choice, depending on the need of your application(s), but it doesn't seem to be included anymore by default.

Optionally, `tid` in combination with `oid` might also be useful if you need to share data across services.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens

And more specifically:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/id-tokens#using-claims-to-reliably-identify-a-user-subject-and-object-id

Comment: If you login the user on the front end, is it save to send the oid to the backend?

Comment: It's safe to send the whole token to the backend, check its signature there, retrieve the oid from the token in the backend and store it in a database.
Never send the oid on its own. The backend should always check if the token is valid.

Comment: Yeah we’re not sure how to do that as the library we’ve found wants the tenant id to verify it and we don’t care about the users tenant as it’s multi tenanted so we have decided to send the code to the front end (via the redirect uri) and then forward the code to the backend to get the token. They recommend libraries, but I haven’t found any that just verify the token.

Comment: There are a bunch of packages and/or ways to do this, but one of the easiest and probably most-used and well-documented ways using the Authorize attribute of ASP.NET: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/aspnet/jwt-validation-and-authorization-in-asp-net-core/